# One Note API The request does not contain a valid authentication token

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

I am trying to share one note class notebook with students but getting permission issues. I have added all the permission required in Azure APP. I am getting access token, refresh token which have the scope of `Notes.ReadWrite.All`

[image: App Permissions]

**Method :-**

```
public static async Task<string> AssignNotebookToStudent(string studentEmail, string fileId)
        {
            var payload = new
            {
                id = studentEmail,
                principalType = "Person"
            };
            
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {tokenValue}");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "application/json");
                var result = await client.PostAsJsonAsync($"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/classNotebooks/{fileId}/students", payload);
                var responseString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return responseString;
}
```

Getting permission response error

[image]

[API Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/how-to/onenote-classnotebook#add-people)

Answer (score 2):

Add scopes with acquiring authentication access token
scope=Notes.Create Notes.Read Notes.ReadWrite

Comment: Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/how-to/onenote-auth#scopes-for-personal-notebooks-that-are-owned-by-the-current-user